# Create Topographic 2D Curves from Polygonal Mesh

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I'm trying to convert a polygonal 3D mesh into a series of topographic curves that represent the part of the mesh at a specific height for every interval. So far, I've come up with the idea to intersect a horizontal plane with the mesh and get the intersection curve(s). So for this mesh: 
[image]

I'd intersect a plane repeatedly at a set interval of precision: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

and etc.

[image]

While this is straightforward to do visually and in a CAD application, I'm completely lost doing this programmatically. How could I achieve calculating this in a programming environment/ what algorithms can I look into to achieve this?

I'm programming in an STL C++ environment (with Boost), loading .obj meshes with [this simple loader,](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) and need simple cartesian 2D points to define the output curve.

Comment: in case anyone is curious, this is to create printing instructions for a 3D printer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to process all the faces in turn and for every face determine the horizontal planes that traverses them. For a given plane and face, check all four vertexes in turn and find the changes of sign (of Zvertex - Zplane). There will be exactly two such changes, defining an edge that belongs to a level curve. (Exceptionally you can find four changes of sign, which occurs when the facet isn't planar - join the points in pairs.)

Every time you find an intersection point, you tag it with the (unique) index of the plane and the (unique) index of the edge that was intersected; you also tag it with the index of the other edge that was intersected in that face.

By sorting on the plane index, you can group the intersections per plane.

For a given plane, using a hash table, you can follow the chain of intersections, from edge to edge.

This gives you the desired set of curves.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense. How exactly though do you find/ what is "the changes of sign?"

Comment: Check the signs of Zvertex-Zplane

Comment: so whether one is positive or negative?

Comment: Yes. Above or below if you prefer.